# How to use token concatenation with scope operator?

Tags: c++

I would like to do something like the following:

```
#define CODE_BLOCK( id) \
    do { \
      someNameSpace::##id foo; \
      foo.ParseFromString( ...); \
      print_##id( foo);
    } while(0)
[...]
CODE_BLOCK( BlahStream);
```

So basically, I want foo to be declared as  type someNameSpace::id where id macro argument.  print_id is defined elsewhere.  Anyways, g++ complains with the message:

```
error: pasting "::" and "BlahStream" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Is there anyway around this?

If it helps, foo is from some userdefined googleprotocol buffer.  My g++ version is 4.7.2 on debian linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `##` operator and it'll work just fine.

e.g.

```
#define stuff(x) \
    std:: x 

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    stuff(cout) << "Hello World\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This appears to have worked.  You saved me lots of work.  The macro is a bit larger than the example.  (I will check mark you, when I am allowed to.  There's a hidden timer on my post.)

Comment: Thanks Rapptz, that helped me today

Answer (score 7):

The preprocessor is already aware that `x::y` is three separate tokens: `x`, `::` and `y`.

Therefore, you do not need any concatenation and, in fact, as you've found out, trying to use it will result in an error.

When you write this:

```
someNameSpace::##id
```

you are writing `someNamespace`, `::y` … and `::y` is not a single token.

You should simply write:

```
someNameSpace::id
```

Now you have `someNamespace`, `::`, `y` … as desired.

Here's your finished code:

```
#define CODE_BLOCK(id) \
    do { \
      someNameSpace::id foo; \
      foo.ParseFromString(...); \
      print_##id(foo);
    } while(0)
// [...]
CODE_BLOCK(BlahStream);
```

<sup>N.B. I've removed the spaces that you keep writing after the `(` symbol, because ew. :)</sup>

Comment: Wow!!  This is great.  Thanks for the very clear explanation.